# Why do we use .format, vs '%.2f' % order.get_cost() in django paypal

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

Just want to ask a quick question to clarify things for me, I am learning django paypal by following a tut and came accross the following when creating my payment processing view when creating paypal_dict:

```
'amount':'%.2f' % order.get_total_cost().quantize(
                                            Decimal('.01')),
'item_name':'Order {}'.format(order.id),
```

My question is, why can't I do the following:

```
'amount':'{}.2f'.format(order.get_total_cost().quantize(
                                            Decimal('.01'))
```

or

```
'item_name':'Order %' % str(order.id)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the first alternative should be `{:.2f}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `%` or format depending on which you prefer.

In a single codebase, I would recommend picking one style and sticking to it for consistency.